# STM32F103 USB CDC

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device, hal-library, stm32f103c8t6

I have a strange problem with USB CDC mode in STM32F103. I have designed PCB with STM32F103 microcontroller and an accelerometer which streams data through USB to PC. I have used STM32CubeMX wizard. It powers itself from USB like this well know blue pill device.

The main problem is that device works perfectly when I plug it for the first time to my PC (it doesn't matter if it's Windows, Ubuntu or Raspberry Pi) but when I disconnect it physically and then when I try to plug it once again it doesn't connect. In general second connection sometimes works sometimes doesn't. Of course, when I reset PC the first connection works again.

Have anyone had a similar problem? I think that posting a solution will be beneficient to many other developers :)

**UPDATE:** I noticed that if I unplug my device and plug it right away it causes "failed to set dtr/rts" but if I wait several seconds and plug it no errors occur. Below I attached dmesg logs.

```
[14388.242015] usb 2-1.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[14388.352862] usb 2-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740
[14388.352867] usb 2-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14388.352870] usb 2-1.2.4: Product: STM32 Virtual ComPort
[14388.352873] usb 2-1.2.4: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[14388.352876] usb 2-1.2.4: SerialNumber: 00000000001A
[14388.427460] cdc_acm 2-1.2.4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[14388.427755] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[14388.427756] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[14399.285342] usb 2-1.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[14399.287602] cdc_acm 2-1.2.4:1.0: failed to set dtr/rts
[14400.786034] usb 2-1.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[14400.896587] usb 2-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740
[14400.896592] usb 2-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14400.896596] usb 2-1.2.4: Product: STM32 Virtual ComPort
[14400.896599] usb 2-1.2.4: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[14400.896601] usb 2-1.2.4: SerialNumber: 00000000001A
[14400.897005] cdc_acm 2-1.2.4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[14424.885653] usb 2-1.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[14446.610270] usb 2-1.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[14446.720618] usb 2-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740
[14446.720622] usb 2-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14446.720625] usb 2-1.2.4: Product: STM32 Virtual ComPort
[14446.720627] usb 2-1.2.4: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[14446.720629] usb 2-1.2.4: SerialNumber: 00000000001A
[14446.721105] cdc_acm 2-1.2.4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Comment: I am afraid you need to post your schematics, especially the power path and hardware reset path. It sounds like you don't have proper reset to your MCU.

Answer (score 1):

It is common problem and you need to have an additional pin to force the enumeration - best after the all initialization code.  (the third pin of the pnp transistor should be connected to the Vdd

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I really appreciated your answer but the problem must be somewhere else. Please check this [ST Discovery board](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084.pdf) scheme. It doesn't have such transistor for disconnecting pull-up resistor and it still works with no such problems.